# Can I compare DDR3 vs GDDR2?

Tags: memory, graphics-card

I'm planning to buy a new graphics card - and I see some of them use DDR and some use GDDR.

I assume GDDR2 is better than DDR2 (correct me if I'm wrong).
Is GDDR2 better than DDR3?

Comment: All of them use GDDR, some just specify it and others don't.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: No, not at all. There are many video cards that use DDR2 memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDDR3 is roughly comparable to DDR2 in terms of technology, but optimized for video cards. GDDR4 is comparable to DDR3 in terms of technology, but optimized for video cards. Overall, your best bet is just to look at benchmark results.

Comment: Thanks - I eventually did and opted for a `DDR3` card